# If an 'else' statement isn't fufilled go back to previous 'if' statement - python, discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and for the fight system I want the code to repeat the damage chunk if the monster isn't dead. I'm not sure how to do this but I know there's something you can do with a while true and break but I don't kno how to implement it. Here is the code:

```
@client.command(name='fight_01')
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def fight_goblin(ctx):
    rng1 = random.randint(1, 3)
    users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] = 5
    rng2 = random.randint(1, 3)
    if rng1 == int('2'):
        await ctx.channel.send(
            "You searched all around and couldn't find a goblin, try again next time :("
        )

     
    else:
       await ctx.channel.send('You encountered a wild goblin!')
       goblin_hp = int('5')
       time.sleep(1.5)
       rng3 = random.randint(1, 10)
       if rng3 == int('3') or int('4') or int('7'):
          users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] = 5
          user = ctx.author
          users = await get_bank_data()
          await ctx.channel.send(
              'The goblin got the first hit and you lost 1hp')          
                users[str(user.id)]['hp'] -= int('1')
          dmg = users[str(user.id)]['max_damage'
          rng4 = random.randint(0, dmg)
          rng5 = str(rng4)
          time.sleep(1.5)
          content1 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage'
          users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] - int(rng4)
          with open("mainbank.json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
          users = await get_bank_data()
          await ctx.channel.send(content1)

          if users[str(user.id)]['hp'] <= 0:
              time.sleep(1.5)
               await ctx.channel.send('You died, better luck next time')
           
                

          if users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] < int('1'):
              content3 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage so you killed the goblin, well done'
              await ctx.channel.send(content3)
              rng6 = random.randint(20, 100)
              users[str(user.id)]['bank'] + rng6
              time.sleep(0.8)
              content4 = 'You gained ' + str(
                  rng6) + ' coins for defeating the goblin'
              await ctx.channel.send(content4)
              with open("mainbank.json", 'w') as f:
                  json.dump(users, f)

           else:
             (This is where I want it to return to the first else: statement)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Advice

Firstly, before ansewring your question, I will give you some advice:

- Don't use `time.sleep` but `await asyncio.sleep` (you have to import it before), you can see why [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=sleep#what-does-blocking-mean).
- You don't have to put `int('5')` in python code, you can just use `5`. Python will automatically know that it's an integer.
- For this line `if rng3 == int('3') or int('4') or int('7'):`, you can use instead `if rng3 in (3, 4, 7):` it's easier and clearer.

Of course, except the first one (which is code breaker), you can continue to use your way of coding!

#### Answer

Now, I will respond to your question. The best way for me to do what you want to do is using `while True` loop. Your code will repeat indefinitely but you are going exit it when you want. Here is your code :

```
@client.command(name='fight_01')
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def fight_goblin(ctx):
    rng1 = random.randint(1, 3)
    users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] = 5
    rng2 = random.randint(1, 3)
    if rng1 == int('2'):
        await ctx.channel.send(
            "You searched all around and couldn't find a goblin, try again next time :("
        )

     
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('You encountered a wild goblin!')
        goblin_hp = int('5')
        time.sleep(1.5) #use await asyncio.sleep(1.5) here rather
        rng3 = random.randint(1, 10)
        if rng3 == int('3') or int('4') or int('7'):
            users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] = 5
            user = ctx.author
            users = await get_bank_data()
            await ctx.channel.send(
                'The goblin got the first hit and you lost 1hp')          
                  users[str(user.id)]['hp'] -= int('1')
            dmg = users[str(user.id)]['max_damage'] #You forgot an ] here so I replaced it
            rng4 = random.randint(0, dmg)
            rng5 = str(rng4)
            time.sleep(1.5) #use await asyncio.sleep(1.5) here rather
            content1 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage'
            users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] - int(rng4)
            with open("mainbank.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(users, f)
            users = await get_bank_data()
            await ctx.channel.send(content1)
            while True: #an infinite loop
                if users[str(user.id)]['hp'] <= 0:
                    time.sleep(1.5)
                    await ctx.channel.send('You died, better luck next time')
                    #If your command stop here you can use return, else use break to get out of the loop, here I will use break
                    break
             
                  
    
                if users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] < int('1'):
                    content3 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage so you killed the goblin, well done'
                    await ctx.channel.send(content3)
                    rng6 = random.randint(20, 100)
                    users[str(user.id)]['bank'] + rng6
                    time.sleep(0.8) #use await asyncio.sleep(0.8) here rather
                    content4 = 'You gained ' + str(
                        rng6) + ' coins for defeating the goblin'
                    await ctx.channel.send(content4)
                    with open("mainbank.json", 'w') as f:
                        json.dump(users, f)
                    #Same here, I will use break
                    break
                else:
                   (This is where I want it to return to the first else: statement)
                   #Here you can use continue to repeat your loop, or just delete this part (an you will return to the first if). To match with your current code, I will use continue
                   continue
```

Your code will repeat itself indefinitely unless you enter one of the first 2 conditions.

Hope my solution will work for you!

Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you so much your a legend